# Themeable Browser Cordova Plugin: Images for back, forward and close Buttons not showing

Tags: angular, cordova, plugins, ionic4

I am building an app for **android** and **ios**. currently just testing on my **android 9.0** phone. I know that `ionic 4` is yet a bit buggy...
My Problem now is that i want to integrate the `Themeable` browser since I can't style the in-app-browser.

And because of that, i tried to use the `Themeable` browser, but the images for the navigation buttons won't show. If I tap the area where they are supposed to be, the app reacts as it should.

I guess I have to get the in-app-browser from **git** and style it myself but before i will do this, is there any solution to my actual problem with the `Themeable` browser?

**I tried:**

- several sizes of the toolbar itself to see if the images just are zoomed in.
- showing just one of the three buttons
- different paths since my pages are in a pages folder
- setting the versions of all plugins to 5.0.0-beta.14 (that actually fixed some other bugs)

```js
openBrowser() {
   const browser: ThemeableBrowserObject = this.tb.create('https://loesdau.de', '_blank', {
      toolbar: {
        height: 50,
        color: '#005A5Aff'
      },
      backButton: {
        wwwImage: '/images/back.png',
        align: 'left',
        event: 'backPressed',
      },
      forwardButton: {
        wwwImage: '/images/forward.png',
        align: 'left',
        event: 'forwardPressed'
      },
      closeButton: {
        wwwImage: '/images/close.png',
        align: 'left',
        event: 'closePressed'
      },
    });

   browser.on('closePressed').subscribe(data => {
        browser.close();
        });
    }
```

My ionic setup:

```
Ionic:


   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.4 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.7.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0, ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin- 
   ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 7 other plugins)
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, after several hours for researching and testing, 
this worked for me:

```
openBrowser() {
   const options: ThemeableBrowserOptions = {
    statusbar: {
      color: '#005A5Aff',
    },
    toolbar: {
      height: 50,
      color: '#005A5Aff',
    },
    backButton: {
      wwwImage: '/assets/images/back.png',
      align: 'left',
      event: 'backPressed',
    },
    forwardButton: {
      wwwImage: '/assets/images/forward.png',
      align: 'left',
      event: 'forwardPressed',
    },
    closeButton: {
      wwwImage: 'assets/images/close.png',
      align: 'right',
      event: 'closePressed',
    },
  };

   const browser: ThemeableBrowserObject = this.tb.create('https://loesdau.de', '_blank', options);

   browser.on('closePressed').subscribe(data => {
        browser.close();
        });

    }
```

because, for some reason i am not able to use native image paths in this plugin as mentioned on the git repo of themeable browser 
https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser

> "wwwImage is like image but loads image from Cordova's www directory
>   instead. This is a fallback solution when you cannot import native
>   resources. Use image property as much as possible."